# does google chat or gtalk support inband bytestream?

Tags: xmpp, gloox

I test with gloox using inbandbytestream to transfer file; seems not working.

Does anyone has experience on that? 
Or recommend a public XMPP that would support IBB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBB does not need any server side support. So I see no reason why IBB should not work on the GTalk servers.

Comment: Correct, if the don't filer out the IBB stanzas then it's a pure client issue.